# Min (5) must be less than or equal to max (-1) in a Range object?

Tags: c#, datatable, datatable.select

I am getting the error in the inner `foreach` while using `Select` in `datatable`.

Here is the code I tried so far

```
foreach (DataRow drOuter in dtLogic.Select("Name='>' OR Name='='"))
{
     foreach (DataRow drInner in dtLogic.Select("ParentId=" + Convert.ToInt64(drOuter["Id"]) + ""))
     {  

     }
}
```

where `Convert.ToInt64(drOuter["Id"])` have the value `2107362180` when I checked in `Immediate Window`. 
 Then why does it throw the below error?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should check for strings and not for numbers so insert single quotes in query `expr='string'`

```
foreach (DataRow drInner in dtLogic.Select("ParentId='" + Convert.ToInt64(drOuter["Id"]) + "'"))
{  

}
```

after this edit you can replace as @Christos answer says

```
Convert.ToInt64(drOuter["Id"])
```

with

```
drOuter["Id"].ToString()
```

Comment: Yes. I had missed single quotes inside datatable.Select(). Since the column contains only int values, still Convert.ToInt64(drOuter["Id"]) is working. Thanks a lot @faby